# How to draw Image Inside Circulr path in Canvas in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-canvas, repaint, drawimage, custom-painter

Hello can anyone tell me how can i draw image inside circular path with scaled image that fits inside the path. I tried but could  not able to figure out and bothering a lot. Please help me.

```
  Paint paint_4 = new Paint()
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
          ..strokeWidth = 1;
    
        Path path_4 = Path();
        path_4.moveTo(size.width * 0.2275000, size.height * 0.2879286);
        path_4.cubicTo(
            size.width * 0.2528667,
            size.height * 0.2879286,
            size.width * 0.2928750,
            size.height * 0.3193143,
            size.width * 0.2928750,
            size.height * 0.4000000);
        path_4.cubicTo(
            size.width * 0.2928750,
            size.height * 0.4449143,
            size.width * 0.2733667,
            size.height * 0.5120714,
            size.width * 0.2275000,
            size.height * 0.5120714);
        path_4.cubicTo(
            size.width * 0.2013083,
            size.height * 0.5120714,
            size.width * 0.1621250,
            size.height * 0.4786286,
            size.width * 0.1621250,
            size.height * 0.4000000);
        path_4.cubicTo(
            size.width * 0.1621250,
            size.height * 0.3550857,
            size.width * 0.1808750,
            size.height * 0.2879286,
            size.width * 0.2275000,
            size.height * 0.2879286);
        path_4.close();
```

> Circular Path to draw Image  and Image need to be properly Scaled to
> be visible

**How Can I Scale assest image to Circular path in properly visibe or fit**
**How can i use Matrix4 to scale ImageShader to canvas**

[image]

```
    canvas.drawPath(
                    path_4,
                    Paint()
                      ..shader = ImageShader(images, TileMode.clamp,TileMode.clamp,Matrix4.identity().scaled(0.19, 0.21).storage));
```

**Here Is my Code**

```
 class ImagePainters extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _ImagePaintersState createState() => _ImagePaintersState();
        }
        
        class _ImagePaintersState extends State<ImagePainters> {
          ui.Image myImage;
        
          Future<ui.Image> _loadAssetImage() async {
            Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image();
        
            AssetImage('assets/face.jpg').resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
                ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
              setState(() {
                myImage = image.image;
              });
              ui.Image img;
        
              img = image.image;
              completer.complete(img);
            }));
        
            return completer.future;
          }
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _loadAssetImage();
          }
        
        
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Center(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(1000, 1000 * 0.7),
                    painter: FinalPainter(context, myImage)),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Canvas Drawing Class

```
                  class FinalPainter extends CustomPainter {
                      final ui.Image images;
                      FinalPainter(BuildContext context, this.images);
                    
                      @override
                      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
                        
                   Paint paint_4 = new Paint()
                      ..color = Colors.black //Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                      ..strokeWidth = 1;
                
                    Path path_4 = Path();
                    path_4.moveTo(size.width * 0.2275000, size.height * 0.2879286);
                    path_4.cubicTo(
                        size.width * 0.2528667,
                        size.height * 0.2879286,
                        size.width * 0.2928750,
                        size.height * 0.3193143,
                        size.width * 0.2928750,
                        size.height * 0.4000000);
                    path_4.cubicTo(
                        size.width * 0.2928750,
                        size.height * 0.4449143,
                        size.width * 0.2733667,
                        size.height * 0.5120714,
                        size.width * 0.2275000,
                        size.height * 0.5120714);
                    path_4.cubicTo(
                        size.width * 0.2013083,
                        size.height * 0.5120714,
                        size.width * 0.1621250,
                        size.height * 0.4786286,
                        size.width * 0.1621250,
                        size.height * 0.4000000);
                    path_4.cubicTo(
                        size.width * 0.1621250,
                        size.height * 0.3550857,
                        size.width * 0.1808750,
                        size.height * 0.2879286,
                        size.width * 0.2275000,
                        size.height * 0.2879286);
                    path_4.close();
```

> Image should be properly visible and can be scaled Circular Path to
> draw Image  and Image need to be properly Scaled to be visible
> **Face should be visible clearly inside the circular path**

```
    canvas.drawPath(path_4, Paint()..shader = ImageShader(images, 
   TileMode.clamp, TileMode.clamp, 
    Matrix4.identity().scaled(0.19, 0.21).storage));}
       
  @override
 bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  {return true;}
}
```

Comment: i may go for  `stack` and `svg`, also `https://shapemaker.web.app/` can help

Comment: yes i tried and i have made custom paint from https://shapemaker.web.app but i want to add image to circular path when user clicks on it